# Error: Call to a member function isDefaultSelector() on null

Tags: magento2

I am facing this issue in my localhost, after i resumed work on my local magento installation.

```
Error: Call to a member function isDefaultSelector() on null in app/design/frontend/Catwalk/default/Algolia_AlgoliaSearch/templates/autocomplete.phtml:11
```

[image]

as you can see in the screen shot, this line is not reflecting in $block output

```
/** @var \Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Block\Algolia $block */
```

This problem is showing only in my localhost, not on stagging and production server.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i have upgraded the version of algolia search module, I have to revert it back, than the problem get fixed automatically.